# How to get JSON Key/Value pairs with JSP

Tags: java, json, jsp

I pass a JSON Object from jersey resource (java class) saved in session Object to a jsp page.

The JSON:

```
{ "dbResult" : [{ 
    "date" : "2016-05-27",
    "firstName" : "ddddd",
    "lastName" : "ccccc",
    "status" : 19
  },
  { "date" : "2016-05-29",
    "firstName" : "aaaaa",
    "lastName" : "bbbbb",
    "status": 2
  },
  { "date" : "2016-05-29",
    "firstName" : "xxxxx",
    "lastName" : "yyyyyy",
    "status" : 94
  }
]}
```

I tried to parse the json (in the jsp) file and get the key/value pairs and display them... but  I keep getting the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

I understand what the error means but all the other tries didn't help.

Code in JSP page:

```
JSONArray jsArr = new JSONArray(session.getAttribute("obj").toString());

for (int j = 0; j < jsArr.length(); j++) {

      JSONObject jsFinal = jsArr.getJSONObject(j);

      Iterator<String> keys = jsFinal.keys();

      while (keys.hasNext()) {
           String key = keys.next();
           System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + jsFinal.get(key));
      }

  }
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: If you are storing the entire JSON under the attribute `obj`, you need to extract the array from `obj` - (noting how the array is under the key `dbResult` and not at the top level)

Comment: you have a invalid json, you missing a quote from 'status'

Comment: @ochi: Yes, true.. Sry, this was just misspelling when copy paste.
it's there in the obj attribute I get via session. Thx for the remark.

Comment: @Sotirios: Array must start with: '[' not with '{' which is correct. Thx.